# Broken protectorate

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I was playing as Spain and I started colonising in South Africa. I started to force countries to be protectorate of me. Then one of the countries just stopped being protectorate. Are the protectorates limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stop being protectorate when they westernize. Check your former protectorate's current tech group

Comment: It is so unworthy. 200 diplomatic power for protectorate and then you have to force vassalize it and most of the time they are too big to be vassals. I think full annexation is better in this case.

Comment: @Dexxrey in the current version of the game AI protectorates no longer westernize. You probably was unlucky to force one into protectorate while he was already westernizing